# jQuery 'scroll' not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following:

```
 var onScroll = function () {
        alert('scroll');
 };
 scrollArea = $('body');
 scrollArea.on('scroll', onScroll);
```

I can do `$('body').scrollTop(400)` and the body scrolls fine, but the `alert` is never called when I manually scroll.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use $('body'), but either $(document) or $(window) to catch the scroll, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    console.log('Scrolled to ' + $(this).scrollTop());
  })
});
```

Here's a working jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4rrm3myL/1/

Answer (score 6):

When you scroll the page, it's `window` that is scrolling not the `body`. So change it to `$(window).on('scroll', onScroll);`

**EDIT:** If you want to bind it to `body` specifically you may do it using `document.body.onscroll = onScroll;`. *But make sure you do not bind any `onscroll` event to `window` in that case*. If you do so, `document.body.onscroll` will be ignored and `window.onscroll` will be listened to.

Check this in action at the fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/sppcdyq9/).